# Unable to Receive Wall Posts after OAuth

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall, authentication

First off, I am new to using Facebook's Graph interface but I've read the documentation and am still unable to retrieve the desired result. First I was able to set up an app account and retrieved my App ID and App Secret, I then set up and advance OAuth Dialog that will ask the user for read_stream permissions (accessing the news feed). I have successfully had three users go throught the authenticator and it allows me to see more of their data but still no wall post (which I assume is the news feed). Below are the steps I followed if someone can help. Thanks. (Sidenote - All urls below came straight from the facebook documentation.)

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://myurl.com/wheredataisdisplayed&scope=read_stream&state=SomethingIndentifiable

returned: state and code=1XXXXXXXX, I then used that to get the OAuth Token

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://myurl.com/wheredataisdisplayed&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&code=1XXXXXXXX

returned access_token = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and expires = 9875067805, I then tried to query the data for that user

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

The end result is more data than what is publicly available but I still don't have access to the users wall data. Another thing I want to do with this is to use it with an infinite session key so that once the user does this once they will have continued access to their data but that I can work out later, Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you accessing `/me/feed` correctly, and if so are you receiving an error message when you do so, or just nothing back?

`/me/feed` should work for this.
You can also request `/me/permissions` to check if the correct permissions were granted which may help you solve the issue

Comment: I wasn't using me/feed, I had assumed (stupidly) that all available information would be returned to me upon completion of authentication. I was able to get it working before you posted but seeing as it's the correct answer no reason in not accepting it.